# make-network-process hangs forever if noone listens on the specified port

Tags: sockets, emacs, tcp, elisp

Is there any way to mitigate this behaviour? It would be best if it returned nil or threw an error.

I.e. suppose I'm trying to connect to an unbound socket on localhost - in that case `make-network-process` blocks and even if afterwards someone binds the socket, it doesn't realize it happened, so, it is basically stuck.

Comment: Can we see the code around your call to `make-network-process`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, had to pay more attention to the documentation. There's a `:nowait` key argument, which will prevent this behaviour. Below is an example code that handles it:

```
(defun haxe-network-process-sentinel (process input)
  (message "haxe-network-process-sentinel <%s>" input)
  (when (stringp input)
      (cond
       ((or
         (haxe-string-starts-with input "failed with code")
         (haxe-string-starts-with input "connection broken by"))
        (setq haxe-network-status 'error))
       ((string= input "open")
        (setq haxe-network-status 'open))
       (t (setq haxe-network-status 'open)
        (haxe-append-server-response input)))))

;;;###autoload
(defun haxe-connect-to-compiler-server ()
  "Starts HaXe compilations server and connects to it.
This function is bound to \\[haxe-connect-to-compiler-server]"
  (interactive)
  (let ((old-proc (get-process haxe-compiler-process)))
    (if (and old-proc (equal (process-status old-proc) 'open))
        (setq haxe-network-process old-proc)
      (haxe-log 3 "Trying to connect to HaXe compiler on %s:%s"
                haxe-server-host haxe-server-port)
      (while (not (eql haxe-network-status 'open))
        (setq haxe-network-process
              (make-network-process
               :name haxe-compiler-process
               :family 'ipv4
               :host haxe-server-host
               :nowait t
               :service haxe-server-port
               ;; :buffer haxe-network-process-buffer
               :sentinel #'haxe-network-process-sentinel
               :filter #'haxe-listen-filter))
        (sleep-for 1))
      (haxe-log 3 "Connected to HaXe compiler"))))
```

Comment: In my experience no-wait t does not work in emacs for windows.